# function to convert list to string using loops

Tags: python

I need to convert a list to a string and have that string print out with a separator between the letters.
I need to use the  function  given. **We must also use a loop.**

Here is what I have so far, but the separator needs to change if called as a hyphon, or star etc. I just am stuck as to how to incorporate a default argument of sep='1,1'.

Any tips and help would be greatly appreciated. Using Python 3.7

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

    my_list = ['H','E','L','p']
    string = ''

    my_string = ''.join(my_list)

    for i in my_string:
        string = string + i + ',' 


    return string
```

output when called should be H,E,L,P or H-E-L-P etc

Comment: `print( "-".join(my_list) )` or `print( ",".join(my_list) )`. You don't need for-loop for this.

Comment: The requirement is to use a loop.

Comment: then don't need `join()` but rather `if` to skip separator before first char.

Comment: If you really _need_ to use a loop, it sounds like a homework assignment, and we'd be doing you a disservice by giving you a full answer. But your code looks like it's almost there. Here's a hint: instead of using `''.join`, just start the loop with `for element in my_list`. If you're stuck with making it into a function, take a look at a tutorial like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `if` to skip separator before first char

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

    string = ''

    for char in my_list:
        if string: # if string is not empty then add separator
            string = string + sep
        string = string + char

    return string

my_list = ['H','E','L','p']
print(to_string(my_list, '-'))
```

---

Other method is to get first char and always add separator. But it needs to check if list is not empty.

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

    if not my_list:
        return ''

    string = my_list[0]

    for char in my_list[1:]:
        string = string + sep + char

    return string

my_list = ['H','E','L','p']
print(to_string(my_list, '-'))
```

Comment: Thank you . The fact we couldn;t use slicing, string or list methods, built-in functions and that it must use a loop was doing my head in. I appreciate your help. Your first response worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do as below

```py
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    return sep.join(my_list)


my_list = ['H','E','L','p']
to_string(my_list, "-")
```

Comment: I have to use a loop. It is a requirement of the question. This is the part that is confusing me

Answer (score 1):

You seem so close already, I'm not sure what is confusing about the loop.

I think this would do it:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep='1,1'):
    sep_string = my_list[0]
    for ch in my_list[1:]:
        sep_string += sep + ch
    return sep_string
```

This looping bit is not a very pythonic approach, but you don't need any conditional statement in it, just use the separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    string = ''

    for i in my_list:
        string = string + i + sep

    return string
```

Output:

```
print(to_sting(['a','p','p','l', 'e'], '-')

a-p-p-l-e
```